# getUserMedia not working on Chrome v50.0.2661.86

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video, webcam, getusermedia

I'm trying to use the getUserMedia method to access my webcam and track my face with clmtrackr (https://github.com/auduno/clmtrackr).
Some weeks ago it was working but since Chrome update to v50 I encounter issues, it uses the replacement video instead of calling my webcam.

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

// check for camerasupport
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {

    var videoSelector = {video : true};
    if (window.navigator.appVersion.match(/Chrome\/(.*?) /)) {
        var chromeVersion = parseInt(window.navigator.appVersion.match(/Chrome\/(\d+)\./)[1], 10);
        if (chromeVersion < 20) {
            videoSelector = "video";
        }
    };

    navigator.getUserMedia(videoSelector, function( stream ) {
        if (video.mozCaptureStream) {
            video.mozSrcObject = stream;
        } else {
            video.src = (window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)) || stream;
        }

        video.play();
    }, function() {
        //it uses this alt video
        insertAltVideo(video);
        alert("There was some problem trying to fetch video from your webcam, using a fallback video instead.");
    });
} else {
    insertAltVideo(video);
    alert("Your browser does not seem to support getUserMedia, using a fallback video instead.");
}
```

PS : It works as I want on Firefox

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.getUserMedia` no longer works in Chrome (it returns `undefined`), use the newer `MediaDevices` interface:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then(function(stream) {
    var videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
    console.log('Got stream with constraints:', constraints);
    console.log('Using video device: ' + videoTracks[0].label);
    stream.onended = function() {
      console.log('Stream ended');
    };
    window.stream = stream; // make variable available to console
    video.srcObject = stream;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // ...
  }
```

See more:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/mediastream-deprecations?hl=en
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/media-devices?hl=en